# span tag shifting down when text inside anchor tag becomes long

Tags: javascript, html, css, flask

I am developing a web app using flask.In the dropdown area shown in pic[image]

when the text becomes too long the close button which is inside the span tag shifts downwards.Following are my html and css codes,

```
 <li class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">Load map <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
            <div id="hahaha" class="dropdown-content">
                {% for maps in map %}
                <a href="#">{{maps[1]}}<span class="close">&times</span></a>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </li>

`.dropbtn {
background-color: #f8f9fa;
color: white;
padding: 16px;
font-size: 16px;
color:#6f7477  ;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
background-color: #f1f1f1
}
.close {
padding: 0px 6px 0px 6px;
float: right;
cursor: pointer;
}

.close:hover{
background-color: #f44336;
color: white;
}`
```

Is there any way to always place the close icon at the end no matter how long  the text is?Thank you.

Comment: It's difficult to see the exact problem if we can't test it directly. Could you provide an example in a code snippet or codepen.io/pen that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `close` button in absolute position and update the `a` tag style related to that.
This will help.

```
.dropdown-content a {
  ...
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 37px; /* 16px + 21px (close button width) You can put the reasonable value here. */
}

.close {
  padding: 0px 6px 0px 6px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 16px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This must solve your problemo!

```css
ul {border:1px solid #9a9a9a;display:inline-block;padding:0;}
ul li {background:#eaeaea;width:120px;position:relative;list-style:none;}
ul li .item {overflow:hidden;width:80px;display:inline-block;text-overflow: ellipsis;}
ul li .close {position:absolute;right:0px;}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="item">red</span><span class="close">X</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="item">green</span><span class="close">X</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="item">blue</span><span class="close">X</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="item">sdfsdfewfdsfxvxdcxvxcsdfsdfsdfdsf</span><span class="close">X</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```